# I did a navbar and my text is sliding out and i want that it slides back in smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
.sidebar a:hover{
   transition: 0.8s;
   color: white;
   margin-left: 30px;   
}
```

1. This is the current code that lets the text slide out
2. If javascript is required it would be nice to tell me how to include javascript code into a html code and i think you already can see that im a absolute beginner

Comment: try `transition: margin 0.8s ease-in `

Comment: Instead of putting the transition property inside `.sidebar a:hover` put it inside `.sidebar a`.

Comment: What do you mean? It slide out to the right and get back to original position smoothly?